# Check if a generic T implements an interface

Tags: java, class, generics, interface, implements

so I have this class in Java:

```
public class Foo<T>{
}
```

and inside this class I want to know if T implements certain interface.

The following code DOES NOT work but it's the idea of what I want to accomplish:

```
if(T.class implements SomeInterface){
    // do stuff
}
```

so I want to check if the class `T` that was passed to Foo have `implements SomeInterface` on its signature.

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Generics, oddly enough, use `extends` for interfaces as well.<sup>1</sup> You'll want to use:

```
public class Foo<T extends SomeInterface>{
    //use T as you wish
}
```

This is actually a requirement for the implementation, *not a true/false check*.

For a true/false check, use unbounded generics(`class Foo<T>{`) and make sure you obtain a `Class<T>` so you have a refiable type:

```
if(SomeInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(tClazz));
```

where `tClazz` is a parameter of type `java.lang.Class<T>`.

If you get a parameter of refiable type, then it's nothing more than:

```
if(tParam instanceof SomeInterface){
```

but this won't work with just the generic declaration.

<sup>1</sup>If you want to require extending a class and multiple interfaces, you can do as follows: `<T extends FooClass & BarInterface & Baz>` The class(only one, as there is no multiple inheritance in Java) must go *first*, and any interfaces after that in any order.

Comment: hi. I really need the true/false check because I'm modifying an existing class. I'm trying your second code but still not sure where `tClass` come from. Any help on that ?

Comment: @Budius Your user needs to at some time, pass in either `Class<T>` from `someInstanceOfT.getClass()` or to pass in an instance of `T` itself. Type erasure won't let you get it otherwise.

Comment: so I can't use the actual generic `T` to test for interface, I'll only be able to use it during `public void add(T object){...}` and test it on the `object`.

Comment: Sadly indeed, not sure it will match my requirements as I need to generate a filename on constructor. Any other way you can think to get the `serialVersionUID` of a possible `Serializable` ?

Comment: ok, I think I'm saved at the end. The guy who originally created this class created a `public abstract Class<T>  myclass();` so I could use `instanceof`. Thanks again.

Comment: It was harder than it should have been understanding that `class<? extends myInterface>` was the right syntax for a class function parameter for my case.  Thanks for the thorough explanation!

Answer (score 4):

you can check it using  isAssignableFrom

```
if (YourInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
    ...
}
```

or to get the array of interface as

```
Class[] intfs = clazz.getInterfaces();
```

Comment: The OP needs a refiable type to get `clazz`, perhaps as accepting `Class<T>` as a parameter or at construction.

Answer (score 0):

Use `isAssignableFrom()`

[isAssignableFrom()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/class_isassignablefrom.htm) determines if the class or interface represented by this Class object is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter.

```
if (SomeInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(T class)) {
  //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, type erasure. And `T Class object` isn't valid syntax. Do you mean an instance of `t`?

Comment: @hexafraction modified my answer