# How can I define a generic class that implements two interfaces?

Tags: java, generics, interface

I don't think this is a duplicate of [Check if a generic T implements an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18783916/check-if-a-generic-t-implements-an-interface), but it may be(??).

So, I want to create a generic interface that only allows objects that implements two interfaces. Alike is a costum interface.

```
public interface AbstractSortedSimpleList<T extends Comparable<T>, Alike> {}
```

If I understand it correctly, Java now tries to create a generic interface `AbstractSortedSimpleList<T,Alike>`, which isnt exactly what I want to achieve. I want `AbstractSortedSimpleList<T>` where T has to implement both `Comparable<T>` and `Alike`.

Later, I want to make a new class

```
public class SortedSimpleList<T> implements AbstractSortedSimpleList<T> {}
```

The point here is to create a `class SortedSimpleList<T>` where T has to be implementing the aforementioned interfaces. But my code does not seem to work very well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/745756/java-generics-wildcarding-with-multiple-classes

Comment: The correct answer is using bounds, but the other option is making Alike to extend Comparable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can give multiple bounds to type parameter:

```
public interface AbstractSortedSimpleList<T extends Comparable<T> & Alike>
```

Then, your `SortedSimpleList` would be like:

```
class SortedSimpleList<T extends Comparable<T> & Alike> implements AbstractSortedSimpleList<T> {}
```

See [JLS §4.4:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4)

> Every type variable declared as a type parameter has a bound. If no bound is declared for a type variable, Object is assumed. If a bound is declared, it consists of either:
>
> - a single type variable T, or
> - a class or interface type T possibly followed by interface types I1 & ... & In.

**Note:**

You can't have such multiple bounds for wildcards though. It's only for type parameters.

**References:**

- [Java Generics FAQs - Type Parameter bounds](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#What%20is%20a%20type%20parameter%20bound?)

Answer (score 8):

Use some generic bounds with the `&` notation

```
interface AbstractSortedSimpleList<T extends Comparable<T> & Alike> {
```

See the official Java tutorial on multiple bounds, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html).

Comment: `public class SortedSimpleList<T> implements AbstractSortedSimpleList<T> {}` this now gives _Bound mismatch: The type T is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<T> & Alike> of the type AbstractSortedSimpleList<T>_

Comment: @hewo The use of `T` in `SortedSimpleTest` is a **new** type variable. You need to specify the bounds on it as well. Otherwise it doesn't fit the bounds that `AbstractSortedSimpleList` expects.

Comment: Edit: Yeah, I just put `T extends Comparable<T> & Alike` in the wrong `<>` hehe. Thanks :)

Comment: @hewo See Rohit's answer below (above). Using `T` in `SortedSimpleList<T>` is declaring a new type variable. Using `T` in `extends AbstractSortedSimpleList<T>` is using `T` as a type argument. That distinction is important when using bounds.